# Paginate entries with offset / limit when templating

Tags: pagination

I've got the pagination function working nicely for a simple for loop of news entries. However I want to split the template up into the first 2 entries as featured items then the next 6 as smaller items. As I paginate through the entries I'd like to keep that layout, however it seems that I cannot use paginatedEntries.limit(2) or paginatedEntries.limit(6).offset(2). Is there another way of doing this?

```
{% paginate craft.entries.section('news').limit(8) as paginatedEntries %}
<section class="two-col">
    <div class="firaslant"><h1>News</h1></div>

        {% for entry in paginatedEntries.limit(2) %}
            {# Show first 2 entries #}
        {% endfor %}    
    </section>

    <aside class="two-col-o">
        {% set tagentries = craft.entries.section('news').limit(null) %}
        {% if craft.tags.relatedTo(tagentries)|length %}
            {% import "_macros/_news.twig" as news %}
            {{ news.tags(tagentries, 'News', 'news') }}
        {% endif %}
        <div class="searchbox">
            <h3>Search in News</h3>
            {% import "_macros/_search.twig" as searchForm %}
            {{ searchForm.simple('news') }}
        </div>

        {% import "_macros/_util.twig" as util %}
        {% if currentUser %}
            {{ util.link('/member-news', 'Browse Member News Articles') }}
        {% endif %}

    </aside>

    {# 6 entries as grid #}
    <div class="clear">
        {% for entry in paginatedEntries.offset(2) %}
                {# Show next 6 articles #}
        {% endfor %}
    </div>


        {% if paginate.prevUrl %}<a href="{{ paginate.prevUrl }}" class="paginate-nav">Previous Page</a>{% endif %}
        {% if paginate.nextUrl %}<a href="{{ paginate.nextUrl }}" class="paginate-nav">Next Page</a>{% endif %}
{% endpaginate %}
```

As soon as I remove .offset(2) or .limit(2) the code functions correctly without errors.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use Twig's [Slice](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/slice.html) function.

```
{% set firstTwo = paginatedEntries|slice(0,2) %}
{% set lastFour = paginatedEntries|slice(2,4) %}
```

Then loop over `firstTwo` for your first items.

```
{% for entry in firtTwo %}
   {# Show first 2 entries #}
{% endfor %}
```

Loop over `lastFour` for your final items.

```
{% for entry in lastFour %}
   {# Show next 6 articles #}
{% endfor %}
```